# Get owner from datatable object

Tags: c#

Is it possible to get the owner from a datatable object?

```
SELECT * FROM DBO.MYTABLE
```

datatable.tableName retrieves only MYTABLE, I would like to get the table owner (dbo) too.
Thanks

Comment: This is not really a programming related question. You run a higher chance of getting the proper answer on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I believe it is. I fill a DataTable object using a dataadapter in c sharp. I can get the name of the table but I'm not able to get the owner.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. The fact that show showed absolutely no C# code kinda threw me off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   this.MyTableAdapter.Connection.Open();
   var schema = this.MyTableAdapter.Connection.GetSchema("Tables");
   this.MyTableAdapter.Connection.Close();
   var owner = schema.Select("TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'")[0]["TABLE_SCHEMA"];
```

Then take a look at the Connection.GetSchema() documentation on MSDN.

Cheers